# Fit to page issue

Tags: html, css

My name is Will and I'm coding a website for some folks. I've ran into a bit of an error. No matter what sort of code I use, the website will not adjust it's self correctly to the page. For example, this is what it looks like on a large screen:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5KLX.jpg

Generally, looks alright. However, the massive space in between the two elements on the sides are awful and create an enviroment of poor contrast and spacing in my opinion.

Here is how it looks on a small screen:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0HFI.jpg

Also generally looks alright. Accept for the missing scroll bar that should be to the right. The picture taken from the smaller computer is how I'd like the site to look on all computers, though I need a scroll bar for it.

Here is the code for that page:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<h1><font color="#000000" size="+1"><marquee  direction="right" bgcolor="green"       scrollamount="3">Website BETA: Version 1.0</marquee></font></h1>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
<div class="fadeIn">
<center>
<div style="display: inline-block;" id="red">
<h1>Hinte's  </h1>
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block;" id="white">
<h1>Liberty  </h1>
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block;" id="blue">
<h1>Theatre</h1>
</div>
</center>
</div>
<br>
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='index.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li class='active'><a href='art.html'><span>Art</span></a></li>
   <li class='active'><a href='biography.html'><span>Biography</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='contact.html'><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
</HEAD>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<body background="grayscale.jpg">
<div style="position:fixed;top:20em;left0em;right:4em;" id="text60">
<p>Gary Edward Hinte</p>
</div>
<div style="position:fixed;top:26em;left0em;right:7em;" id="text30">
<p>American Political Artist</p>
</div>
<div style="position:fixed;top:22em;left:1em;right:40em;">
<img class="grayBox" style="border: 0px solid black;
            border-radius: 10px;
            -moz-border-radius: 10px;
            -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 10px;" width="600px" height="500px" src="JulianA.jpg">
</div>
</body>
<title>HLT - Home</title>
</HTML>
```

Comment: 1. Where's the end of your head tag and start of your body tag. 2. What do you mean 'it won't adjust its self'

Comment: Sorry just found them. Why do you have list elements in your head? Have you reset padding and margins?

Comment: I would recommend you read some basic tutorials for web design including HTML and CSS. The whole structure of the page is incorrect.

Comment: The other comments and the answer are right. It's great to learn by experimentation, but you're going to get tangled up in knots if you don't read up on some of the basics. I did a quick google and found a lot of crud, but this might be a place to start reading: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/building-html5-css-webpages/

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
  <head>
     <title>HLT - Home</title>
     <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
     <link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>

<body>
<!--All of your content in here-->

</body>
</html>
```

I would appreciate if you put the stylesheet too, also, don't copy and paste your whole document. Just the parts you are having trouble with

I would recommend a few HTML and CSS tutorials.  You have the wrong idea. a `body` element is where ALL the content goes besides imports and stuff.  The `head` element is where imports and titles and stuff go, NOT CONTENT YOU WANT TO DISPLAY.

And lastly, I'm confused on why you're even using a stylesheet.  It seems you're using all these old methods for styling in HTML.  Such as:  `center` and `font` and you're apply most of your styles directly into the element.

To center it like you want on your smaller picture.  I would add a `max-width: 1280px;` to your styles, or make a container DIV with a specified width around all of your content in your body section.

Hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

Im sorry but your website is setup all wrong. try this.

```
<html>
    <title>Page Name</title>
    <meta tags />
    <styles that you need to link to />

    <body>
    anything you want people to see goes here!!!
    <scripts go here />
    </body>
</html>
```

Also it is impossible to help you with out your css and for your elements to be properly displayed they must be put like I showed you.

If you want your site to look the same or somewhat the same you need to use %%%% to style your elements so they are responsive to the window size.

To align your elements look into useing: position, margin, padding, left right top and bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a wrapper and putting your div's in the BODY like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
<title>HLT - Home</title>
  </head>
  <body>


<h1><font color="#000000" size="+1"><marquee  direction="right" bgcolor="green"       scrollamount="3">Website BETA: Version 1.0</marquee></font></h1>

<div id="wrapper">

<div class="fadeIn">
<center>
<div style="display: inline-block;" id="red">
<h1>Hinte's  </h1>
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block;" id="white">
<h1>Liberty  </h1>
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block;" id="blue">
<h1>Theatre</h1>
</div>
</center>
</div>
<br>
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='index.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li class='active'><a href='art.html'><span>Art</span></a></li>
   <li class='active'><a href='biography.html'><span>Biography</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='contact.html'><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
</HEAD>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<body background="grayscale.jpg">
<div style="position:fixed;top:20em;left0em;right:4em;" id="text60">
<p>Gary Edward Hinte</p>
</div>
<div style="position:fixed;top:26em;left0em;right:7em;" id="text30">
<p>American Political Artist</p>
</div>
<div style="position:fixed;top:22em;left:1em;right:40em;">
<img class="grayBox" style="border: 0px solid black;
            border-radius: 10px;
            -moz-border-radius: 10px;
            -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 10px;" width="600px" height="500px" src="JulianA.jpg">
</div>


</div> <!--closing wrapper-->
</body>
</html>
```

And add this to your css file

```
#wrapper {
width:1200px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: auto;
}
```